# min function that ignores negative values in php 

Tags: php, min

I have three numbers:

```
$a = 1
$b = 5
$c = 8
```

I want to find the minimum and I used the PHP `min` function for that. In this case it will give `1`.

But if there is a negative number, like

```
$a = - 4
$b = 3
$c = 9
```

now the PHP `min()` should give `$b` and not `$a`, as I just want to compare positive values, which are `$b` and `$c`. I want to ignore the negative number.

Is there any way in PHP? I thought I will check if the value is negative or positive and then use `min`, but I couldn't think of a way how I can pass only the positive values to `min()`.

Or should I just see if it's negative and then make it 0, then do something else?

Comment: create an array, filter the array, if value < 0, delete this array element, then use min() on the array

Comment: *shudder*  The strings "-ve" and "+ve" are not words in the English language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should simply filter our the negative values first.

This is done easily if you have all of them in an array, e.g.

```
$a = - 4;
$b = 3;
$c = 9;

$values = array($a, $b, $c);
$values = array_filter($values, function($v) { return $v >= 0; });
$min = min($values);

print_r($min);
```

The above example uses an anonymous function so it only works in PHP >= 5.3, but you can do the same in earlier versions with

```
$values = array_filter($values, create_function('$v', 'return $v >= 0;'));
```

[**See it in action**](http://www.ideone.com/shbEd).

Comment: BLAST YOU... beaten by mere seconds.

Comment: You save my day :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$INF=0x7FFFFFFF;

min($a>0?$a:$INF,$b>0?$b:$INF,$c>0?$c:$INF)
```

or

```
min(array_filter(array($a,$b,$c),function($x){
    return $x>0;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepad.org/DVgMs7JF

```
<?
$test = array(-1, 2, 3);

function removeNegative($var)
{
   if ($var > 0)
       return $var;
}

$test2 = array_filter($test, "removeNegative");

var_dump(min($test2));
?>
```